# Group matching numbers in random order in R

Tags: r, sorting, random, montecarlo

I'm working on a Monte-Carlo simulation type problem and need to generate a vector of repeated random numbers, with the matching numbers grouped together, but in random order.

It's easier to explain with an example. If I had:
1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12

I would like it sorted as:
7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1 (or with the groups of matching numbers in any order but ascending/descending).

The reason I need the random order is because my MC simulation is for 2 variables, so if both are in order they won't vary independently.

I've got as far as:

```
sort(rep(runif(50,1,10),10), decreasing = FALSE)
```

Which generates 50 random numbers between 1 and 10, repeats each 10 times, then sorts the 50 groups of 10 matching random numbers in ascending order (or it could easily be descending order if I changed "FALSE" to "TRUE"). I just can't figure out the last step of getting 50 groups of 10 matching numbers in random order. Can anyone help?

Comment: How about have one variable in increasing order and the other one in random order then just group by both variables when getting summaries?

Comment: What do you mean ascending descending?

Comment: `y=by(x,x,FUN=I); unlist(y[sample(length(y),length(y))])`

Comment: `unlist((a<-split(x,x))[sample(b<-length(a),b)])`

Comment: @hpsejo626 - yes, I think that would be fine. Off the top of my head it shouldn't matter whether both variables are randomly ordered or one random, one ascending/descending. As long as they're independent.

Comment: @Onyambu - by 'ascending/descending' I mean that I don't want to end up with "1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3..." or "12, 12, 12, 7, 7, 7,...".I wasn't 100% sure how to replicate your solutions (though they seem pretty similar to akrun's). Feel free to post a more detailed version if you can be bothered.

Comment: I did post this before akrun posted the solution. Look at the time...

Comment: I guess your point is that it is not random... because 3 cannot follow 1nor can 7follow 3 nor can 12 follow 7.. nor can 1 follow 3 nor can 3 follow 7 etc.. this means you will have to ORDER your data and not to SAMPLE THEM.L. You order them in such a way that they dont follow each other

Comment: Haha, didn't see the timestamp sorry. Back at work for the week and tried your solutions. Both work well, thanks!

To clarify re your last comment, it's ok if some of the numbers end up sequentially ordered due to chance, I just need to avoid them being systematically in order. (Why is this so hard to explain!?!)

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option with `split`

```
unlist(sample(split(v1, v1)), use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  3  3  3  1  1  1 12 12 12  7  7  7
```

---

Or another option is `match` with `unique`

```
v1[order(match(v1, sample(unique(v1))))]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12)
```

Comment: Thanks! The match/unique version seems to do exactly what I'm after. 

The unlist one always returns the variables in the same order for me, which isn't a major, but seems to suggest it's not properly random.

Comment: @TimM I wrapped with `sample` on the `list` i.e. `sample(split(v1, v1))`.  Perhaps you noticed that or not

Comment: Both the options worked for me. Very neat solutions.

Comment: @akrun - back at work for the week and tried the first solution again. Worked fine this time. Not sure what I did wrong last time. I only tested it 3 or 4 times, so maybe I just got the same sequence by bad luck.

Thanks for your help anyway. Am going ahead with your solution and it works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

An option could be as:

```
v <- c(1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12, 1, 3, 7, 12)
lst <- split(v, unique(v))

sapply(sample(seq(length(lst)),length(lst)), function(i)lst[[i]])

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3   12    7    1
#[2,]    3   12    7    1
#[3,]    3   12    7    1

#OR for having just a vector 

as.vector(sapply(sample(seq(length(lst)),length(lst)), function(i)lst[[i]]))
#[1]  3  3  3 12 12 12  7  7  7 1  1  1
```